# switches and functions

Tags: c++

When i run the program and select premium it runs it put then it also runs the function for regular service. the problem is in int main at the lines. What did i do wrong? IT says i didnt explain the problem clearly enough, not sure why so here is more text to get around that.

```
premiumserv = premserv(daymin, nightmin); 
regularserv = regserv ();
```

Full code below

```
/************************************************/
/* Author:     Sam LaManna                      */
/* Course:     CSC 135 Lisa Frye                */
/* Assignment: Program 3 Cell Phone Bill        */
/* Due Date:   10/20/2011                       */
/* Filename:   program3.cpp                     */
/* Purpose:    This program calculates and      */
/*             prints the bill for a cellular   */
/*             telephone company                */
/************************************************/



//TODO:
//Fix account number issue: large numbers cause intfinte loop. Maybe use string?
//Complete premium and regular service calculation functions
//Output function - Figure out how to print 



#include <iostream>    //Basic input/output
#include <iomanip>     //Manipulators 

using namespace std;

void instruct();       //Function declaration for printing instructions
int accnum ();         //Function declaration for account number
char servcode ();      //Function declaration for service code
float regserv ();      //Function declaration for regular service
float premserv (int& daymin, int& nightmin);     //Function declaration for premium service
void output (float premiumserv, float regularserv);        //Function declaration for printing results

int main()
{
  int accountnum = 0;     //Var for account number
  char servicecode = 'a';     //Var for service code
  float premiumserv = 0;      //Var for premium service total
  float regularserv = 0;      //Var for regular service total
  int daymin = 0;
  int nightmin = 0;

  instruct();     //Function call to print instructions

  accountnum = accnum();     //Function call to input account number

  servicecode = servcode();  //Function call to get service code

  switch(servicecode)        //Switch to determine which calc to use
    {
    case 'r':
      break;
    case 'R':
     regserv ();
      break;
    case 'p':
      break;
    case 'P':
     premserv (daymin, nightmin);
      break;
    }

  premiumserv = premserv ( daymin, nightmin);     //Function call for regular service

   regularserv = regserv ();      //Function call for premium service

  cout <<"total" << premiumserv <<"day" << daymin << "night " << nightmin;

  return 0;
}



/************************************************/
/* Name: instruct                               */
/* Description: Prints instructions to user     */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: N/A                            */
/************************************************/

void instruct()
{
  cout << "\n" <<  "This program will calculate the cellular telephone bill for a given customer when " << "\n" 
       << "given the correct inputs. ";
  //Prints instructions to user

  return;
}

/************************************************/
/* Name: accnum                                 */
/* Description: Get user account number         */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: accnum                         */
/************************************************/

int accnum()
{
  int accnum = 0;                               //Define var for account number
  char accyn = 'n';                             //Define char for user verify
  int i = 1;                                    //Define var for sentinel loop


  do {
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "Please enter your account number: ";
    cin >> accnum;
    while ((accnum < 0) && (i<3))
      {
    cout << "\n" << "Error - invalid number, please try again.";
    cout << "\n" << "Please enter your account number: ";
    cin >> accnum;
    i++;
    if (i == 3)
      {
        cout << "\n" << "Too many invalid attempts, program terminating." << "\n"
         << "Have a nice day. " << "\n" << "\n";
        exit (0);
      }     //end if
      }     //end while
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Your account number is: " << accnum << "\n"
     << "Is this correct? [y/n] ";
    cin >> accyn;
  } while (accyn != 'y');     //end do/while loop


  return accnum;
}

/************************************************/
/* Name: servcode                               */
/* Description: Get service type                */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: servcode                       */
/************************************************/

char servcode()
{
  char servcode = 'a';                             //Define var for service code
  char serviceyn = 'n';                            //Define var for user verify
  int i = 1;                                       //Define var for sentinel loop

  do {
    cout << "\n" << "Please enter your service code, [R]egular or [P]remium:" << "\n";
    cin >> servcode;
    while ((servcode != 'R' && servcode != 'P' && servcode != 'r' && servcode != 'p' ) && (i < 3))
      {
    cout << "\n" << "Error - invalid service code, please try again. ";
    cout << "\n" << "Please enter your service code: ";
    cin >> servcode;
    i++;
    if (i == 3)
      {
        cout << "\n" << "Too many invalid attempts, program terminating." << "\n"
         << "Have a nice day. " << "\n" << "\n";
        exit (0);
      }     //end if
      }     //end while
    cout << "\n" << "You entered: " << servcode << "\n"
     << "Is that correct? [y,n]";
    cin >> serviceyn;
      } while (serviceyn != 'y'); // end do/while loop

  return servcode;
}

/************************************************/
/* Name: regserv                                */
/* Description: Calculations for regular serv   */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: regserv                        */
/************************************************/

float regserv ()
{
  int regmin = 0;     //Var for number of minutes used
  float regserv = 0;  //Var for cost for regular service


  cout << "\n" "Please enter the minutes used: " << "\n";
  cin >> regmin;
  regserv = (regmin - 50) * 0.2 + 10;

  return regserv;

}

/************************************************/
/* Name: premserv                               */
/* Description: Calculations for premium serv   */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: premserv                       */
/************************************************/

float premserv (int& daymin, int& nightmin)
{
   float daytotal = 0;     //Var for day total
  float nighttotal = 0;   //Var for night total
  float premserv = 0;     //Var for premium service cost

  cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the day (6AM - 6PM): " << "\n";
  cin >> daymin;
  cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the night (6PM - 6AM): " << "\n";
  cin >> nightmin;

  daytotal = (daymin - 75) * 0.1;
  nighttotal = (nightmin - 100) * 0.05;
  premserv = 25 + daytotal + nighttotal;

  return premserv;

}
```

Comment: how so, i listed the problem and were i think the problem is. I also included full code. what else is there?

Comment: As a side note, I'm assuming that you want 'P' and 'p' to run the premium service and 'R' and 'r' to run the regular one. Is this what you want? Because right now if you enter 'r' or 'p' it doesn't work, it reaches the `break;` and exits right away. What you want is to remove that break, like so:
case 'r':
case 'R':
    regserv();
case 'p':
case 'P':
  premserv(daymin, nightmin);

Comment: The code is helpful, but if you didn't have it your question would have made no sense because we don't know anything about what the program you are debugging does.

Comment: it works, ive been testing with p

Comment: @Jesse Emond:  I believe the proper method is to convert the letter using `tolower` or `toupper` before making comparisons.  This reduces the size of the code and improves readability.

Comment: it works because it runs the service after the `switch` block (which is the problem you're looking for within this question) but if you want to call one or the other you'll have to remove the 2 calls at the end, and then you'll see that p doesn't work (at least I'm pretty sure it shouldn't).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I agree, but I just highlighted the problem, so that OP knows if it ever goes wrong. But you are definitely right, `tolower` or `toupper` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `regserv()` or `premserv()` inside the switch statement, but then you unconditionally call them both immediately after the switch.

The comment on the switch suggests that you've misunderstood the semantics of switch. It doesn't "select" what's to going to happen next, it actually runs the code inside the switch, so you don't need to invoke them after the switch. However, don't forget to assign the `premiumserv` and `regularserv` variables and perform output inside the switch statement, e.g.:

```
...
case 'R':
    regularserv = regserv();
    cout << ... regularserv ...
    break;
...
```

Comment: how do i save the output from the functions then. thats what im trying to do after the switch statement

Comment: assign the output of the functions to variables, just like you do outside the switch statement.

Comment: Im not assigning the output of the fuctions in the switch statement. Thats what i have those 2 lines of code below the switch

Comment: @SamLaManna: I've amended my answer to explain this.

Comment: @SamLaManna: [RE: your second comment] That's precisely what you are doing wrong. You shouldn't run those functions outside the switch because they run unconditionally, thus negating the purpose of the switch.

Comment: When i assigned the 'premiumserv' and 'regularserv' variables it no longer runs the functions

Comment: Reply to myself removed some 'break' s and all is well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem might be in this section of code:

```
  switch(servicecode)        //Switch to determine which calc to use
    {
    case 'r':
      break;
    case 'R':
     regserv ();
      break;
    case 'p':
      break;
    case 'P':
     premserv (daymin, nightmin);
      break;
    }

  premiumserv = premserv ( daymin, nightmin);     //Function call for regular service

   regularserv = regserv ();      //Function call for premium service

  cout <<"total" << premiumserv <<"day" << daymin << "night " << nightmin;
```

Here you are switching on the service code and calling regserv and premserv depending.  Then afterwards you call these functions, but in the case of regserv you assign the return value to a variable that is then never referenced again.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure what your program is supposed to be doing, but from the look of it you want to call the regserve function when the user inputs 'R' or 'r' and premserve when the user enters 'P' or 'p'. But in your switch statement when you recieve a 'p' or 'r' you immediately call break. What break will do is continue execution after the end of the switch statement instead of falling into the 'P' or 'R' cases.

The best way to fix that would be to add an explicit call to regserve or premserve for each of the cases (you can let it fall through by not including the break but it makes it easier to read by explicitly stating the action for each case).